# update session variable without page refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to update the session variable on page 1, when click on a link in iframe (external page).
session variable is successfully set when i click on iframe's link.
the problem is i need to refresh the page 1 to update that session variable on page1.

[image]

how to resolve this.any ajax , jquery help.
THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML `a href` link:

```
<a href="#" id="clickme">Update Session</a>
```

jQuery codes:

You can send data with line of `data: { varname: 'here we go'}`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#clickme").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'update.php',
        data: { varname: 'here we go'},
        success:function(response){
           alert(response);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

update.php file:

You can get sent var with `$_POST["varname"]`

```
<?php
   $_SESSION["varname"] = $_POST["varname"];
   echo $_SESSION["varname"];
?>
```

Comment: hi i try your code but not working :( ne  y is it

Comment: Paste to question your codes.

Comment: bora, i tied to call the function from <a href="#" id="clickme">Update Session</a> but it's not working even the alert.
could you please kindly recheck your code for me?

Comment: @KarvinMendis I tried now, and its working perfectly. I updated again. Try now